# Trying to summarize line lengths within grid cells in R

Tags: r, line, polygon, r-sf

I am trying to calculate the sum of line lengths within grid cells in R. I have been using this as a reference https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/289350/calculate-sum-of-line-lengths-in-r

The problem I am having is that when I create a grid using st_make_grid, there is no ID column for when I match the line intersection lengths to the grid. I have tried using as.Spatial to convert the grid to a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame so that I can add columns, but then st_length and st_intersections won't work because the grid is no longer an "sf" object. What would be the best workaround to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the grid from sfc to sf object via a `sf::st_as_sf()`

Consider this example, built on the well known & much loved nc.shp dataset that ships with {sf}

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

shape <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) %>%  
  summarise() %>% 
  st_geometry() %>% 
  st_cast("POLYGON") %>% 
  st_cast("LINESTRING")

# a line around North Carolina - to get a line object
plot(shape)
```

[image]

```
grid <- st_make_grid(x = st_bbox(shape),
                     n = c(30, 10)) %>% 
  st_as_sf() %>% # this is the part!
  mutate(id = 1:nrow(.)) # now tis possible to add a row id

intersection <- st_intersection(grid, shape) %>% 
  mutate(lenght = st_length(.)) %>% 
  st_drop_geometry() # complicates things in joins later on


grid <- grid %>% 
  left_join(intersection, by = "id")

plot(grid["lenght"])
```

[image]

Comment: glad to be of service! :)

Comment: Actually I do have an additional question. How do I get the sum of all the line lengths in the grid cell? The way it is currently set up I get a length for each line segment that is within the cell, but since I have multiple line segments I need to get the sum. Can I use fun=sum within the st_length function somehow?

Comment: this gets tricky, as I have close to zero imagination and can't actually see your data, but in theory you should be able to run a summarise() call your intersection objects grouped by the newly introduced `id` field & summing the lengths of interections per cell

Comment: can you clarify your comment, "# complicates things in joins later on"? @JindraLacko

Comment: @JessicaBurnett in the code sample I provided I do a `dplyr::left_join()` between two data frame objects - grid and the intersection line sums. If the intersections had a geometry I would be joining two sf objects, and the function would have hard time deciding which geometry should be the "correct" one. By dropping the intersection geometry - as I am interested only in line length - I avoid that problem.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!